# Who controls banks in Diamond's model?

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, financial-economics, political-economy

In Diamond's model banks are delegated to monitor borrowers for the investors, in this case, who monitors the banks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody does. The Diamond's classic 1984 model does not include any banking supervision. The model tries to explain why specialized financial intermediaries exists as opposed to having pure peer to peer lending. As such it does not model bank supervision.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So why investors delegate the monitoring to the banks if these are not monitored by anyone? They could simply monitor their own investments. 
What I'm sayng is: the problem of monitoring an investment transfers to the problem of monitoring the bank they lend money, how do they solve this?

Comment: @RobertoPalermo because bank is unlikely to have solvency issues. The unconditional probability that single individual defaults is several orders of magnitude higher than the unconditional probability that bank defaults. Also, bank has profit motive. Also the whole point is that monitoring for bank is cheaper. Of course they could do their own monitoring, but bank can do that cheaper than individual investor via specialization